# javascript not working on data returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a JavaScript abc.js that is running on a div (class one) element. The script is working fine on elements located within the div element in the html code, but it's not working on data returned from success ajax call that appended to id=tow element.

Here is the code;

**HTML**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
<div class="one">
    <ul id="tow">
        <li>
            <a href="images.jpg">
                  <img src="images/a1.jpg"/>
                  <span>
                  <div class="title"><img src="Images/a2.jpg" /></div>
                  </span>
            </a>
        </li>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').click(function () {
        if (cid != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: {
                    aid: aid,
                    cid: cid,
                    sid: sid
                },
                success: function (data) {
                 $("#tow").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The data returned from success ajax is:

```html
<li> <a href="images3.jpg"><img src="images/a4.jpg"/>
         <span>
          <div class="title"><img src="Images/a5.jpg" /></div>
         </span>
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why do you add `data` as argument to the empty method? Just use `.empty()`

Comment: You could replace the separate `.empty()` and `.append()` with just `.html(data)`.

Comment: Check if there are any errors in console

Comment: Put a log statement in your success function, is that being called? While your code above is incorrect usage of `empty()`, that won't throw any show stopping errors, as it stands, this should work.

Comment: @tymeJV i put log statement console.log('abc') within the success function but its not called. the data returnd from the ajax is returned succesfuly but the java script not run on this data.

Comment: Sounds like a failed response. Try adding a `dataType` in your AJAX properties of `html`

Comment: @tymeJV it solved the console log problem, but im still facing the main problem.

Comment: Log your `data` variable, is it valid HTML?

Comment: yes its valid html but this is not my problem, the data from ajax is returned succesfully to the html and shown in the browser. the problem is that the javascript not work on this ajaxs' returned data.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(jqXHR)
    {     
       $("#tow").html(jqXHR.responseText);                        
    }
```

jQuery ajax returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). What you are interested in is its responseText property.

Comment: i tried your solution but its still not working. the data returned succesfully from ajax call but the javascript not run on this data

Comment: @user2746564 are you sure about the content of your response? Maybe your ajax is returning a wrapper around the html?

Comment: @ArunKillu not sure what you mean, where would you need delegation?

Comment: @Christophe im used alert(data) to check what returned from the ajax and there is no wrapper. the upper element is li element.

Comment: @user2746564 ok. That's really strange, because alert(data) should not return your response HTML. Are you using a recent version of jQuery?

Comment: @Christophe sorry , i meant it's alert the html code of the data. i use it to check if the data returned is correct.

Comment: Anyone has a solution for this? it also didn't work for me, I already using .on and in click event and still no luck and yes use the jqXHR.responseText instead of object data :(